# How to use the c/c++ code to change ubuntu's background

Tags: 14.04, c

Or any other way.I want to make an application to make my desktop pretty.

Comment: What do you mean with "c/c++" code? Changing background is nothing more than use a command (called gsettings) to point to an image.

Comment: Use the GSettings API: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html

Comment: Another option, which I think is what the OP is looking for, is to get the root window and draw that surface.  The question is addressed on SO somewhere.  I remember reading it, but my 5 second search didn't turn it up.  Uptick to @muru though for changing the setting.  Doing it to the root window lets it work even on desktops that don't draw wallpaper like i3wm.

Comment: And my google-fu is stronger than my stackexchange-search-fu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220826/changing-wallpaper-on-linux-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blatant copy paste from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220826/changing-wallpaper-on-linux-programmatically)

Though the question was gnome-specific, there's also a way to deal with the wallpaper that is not depepndant on the higher layer toolkits. You should be able to deal with the root window (which the wallpaper is, in fact) by studying the source of [xsetroot.c](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xsetroot/tree/xsetroot.c), the most interesting part of which I copypaste here:

```
static void
SetBackgroundToBitmap(Pixmap bitmap, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    Pixmap pix;
    GC gc;
    XGCValues gc_init;

    gc_init.foreground = NameToPixel(fore_color, BlackPixel(dpy, screen));
    gc_init.background = NameToPixel(back_color, WhitePixel(dpy, screen));
    if (reverse) {
        unsigned long temp=gc_init.foreground;
        gc_init.foreground=gc_init.background;
        gc_init.background=temp;
    }
    gc = XCreateGC(dpy, root, GCForeground|GCBackground, &gc_init);
    pix = XCreatePixmap(dpy, root, width, height,
                        (unsigned int)DefaultDepth(dpy, screen));
    XCopyPlane(dpy, bitmap, pix, gc, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, (unsigned long)1);
    XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(dpy, root, pix);
    XFreeGC(dpy, gc);
    XFreePixmap(dpy, bitmap);
    if (save_colors)
        save_pixmap = pix;
    else
        XFreePixmap(dpy, pix);
    XClearWindow(dpy, root);
    unsave_past = 1;
}
```